# 'Some cookies are misusing the recommended “sameSite“ attribute' On OneDrive embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, embed, onedrive

I have embedded a video from onedrive on my website. When I open the site I get an error that goes something like:

Some cookies are misusing the recommended “sameSite“ attribute (10)

The video does not play but after ~5 seconds it opens the onedrive website. Not sure why.

I have tried using google drive but instead of the video I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUekF.jpg)

Can someone help me with this.
If I need to provide more info then ask.